# Black renders issue

Tags: rendering

I'm running the 2.80 version.
When ever I render an image out of my scene all I get is black. Everything shows up just fine in the rendered viewport.

All other scenes seem to render without any issues though.

Any of the solution in similar cases yielded no results.

Other things related:
I recently upgraded my Graphics card to the new 5700 XT model. I previously had a GTX 1070.
I uninstalled the Graphics card drivers with DDU and of course then updated to the latest AMD drivers to avoid any driver conflicts.

[image]

Comment: Have you choice Cycles Render Device in System preferences?
After press render button do you see something like "Compiling render kernels" or "Loading render kernels" ?
Are you using correct render layer? Check passes!
Do you have environment light or lights in current render layer?
Check Exposure in Film and in Color Management!
I can still guess a little without screenshots or a scene file )

Comment: I have the my processor and Graphics card selected as the rendering devices. 
And yes I do see the "Compiling render kernels" show up once I hit render.

I have the "combined" and "Z" checked under the passes. 
All the layers that I want to be rendered have the "use for rendering" box checked.
Exposure is set to 0.000 changing that to 1.000 did nothing.

Could there be any other reasons why this happens?

Comment: direct and environment lights. please use blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to share you scene

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6663" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6663/)

Here it is.

Answer (score 0):

The black render may be also caused by a disconnected composite node. In case you use compositing in your project, can you check that you have a composite node and it's connected to your compositor tree?

Comment: From the render layers node it's connected from the "image port" to the composite nodes "image port" Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. Sorry i didn't guess without a file..

First you should control not only hiddenness, but also viewport and render visibility by the switches in outliner filter:

[image: toggle]

You managed to hide useless objects but it still was able to render:

[image: outliner]

Object "Cube.001" was hidden but on render blocked the active camera.

[image: camera blocked]

Now the donut so delicious (with some color correction)..

[image: final result white balansed]

and feel free compress files while saving

[image: compress files]
[image]

almost three times lighter

Comment: AH! Thank you! Of course the solution was right under my nose lol.